# Removing a decimal place in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hunk of HTML, that is generated through PHP, and generates a number with two decimal places, within a span, with the class of "amount":

```
<span class="amount">200.00</span>
```

What I am looking to do is use a client side method to alter the text within the span so it does NOT have decimal places (i.e. in this case; 200), so I don't need to edit any of the original PHP, as this is generated through a plugin.

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: so loop through the elements on document ready and remove the decimal...

Comment: Rectify means?, to any specific format or just the value

Comment: Format, for data purposes it needs to keep the .00 in the database, but when I load it on the page I need it to not show that.

Comment: edited, sorry, poorly worded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.each` method to loop through each element, and then just use the split method to get the integer part

```js
$(function(){
  //Go through each element
  $(".amount").each(function(item){
     //split the text on the dot, and then take the front piece
     $(this).text( $(this).text().split(".")[0] );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="amount">200.00</span><br />
<span class="amount">220.40</span><br />
<span class="amount">5.40</span><br />
<span class="amount">90.95</span><br />
```

Note if you know before hand that the values will always have a `.00` value you can just use

```
$(this).text( +$(this).text() );
```

by forcing it to be a number (by having the + in front) and back to a string (when it gets set as the element text) will cause it to lose the decimal part

Answer (score 0):

You can get value as $("span.amount").text().replace(".",""). In JS it would replace just one instance of ".", you are good enough to use this.

Comment: this would cause the values to be wrong as it would make `200.00` be `20000` which are not the same values

Comment: Yes, to understand your requirement, i commented on original question, but thought of giving a try.

Comment: That is why, i curiously posted this, anyway , you got a reply above